# 2D vector with parametrized constructor

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I'm trying to create two dimensional `std::vector`, that will hold objects of this class I inherited.
The problem I have is that this class has only one constructor, and that uses one parameter (`std::string` to be precise).

```
#define HEIGHT 4
#define WIDTH 4 

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

static vector<vector<Reaper> > reaper(HEIGHT, vector<Reaper> (WIDTH));
```

This should create 4x4 matrix of Reaper objects in my vector. At least I know it would work if I had constructor with no parameters available.

But, this is how I would instantiate `Reaper` object:

```
Reaper r0("R0");
Reaper* r1 = new Reaper("R1");
```

Now, I can't figure out how to include this constructor into my vector construction?

Comment: Don’t use `#define` for constants. Don’t use `new` to instantiate objects. Furthermore, for matrix-like two-dimensional vectors you almost always want to use a one-dimensional vector of length `width * height`, and calculate the index based on your two  coordinates (all wrapped in a class, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `vector(size_t n, const T& t)` constructor to initialize the inner vector of `reaper`s to some initial constant value, like

```cpp
static vector<vector<Reaper> > reaper(HEIGHT, vector<Reaper> (WIDTH, Reaper("value")));
```

You seem to use this once for the outer vector --- you can use it for the inner vector as well.

Alternately, you can create a 2d-vector of pointers to `reaper`s.